# An inequality concerning the relation between Riemann integral and the discrete sum

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove that for all $n\in\mathbb{N,}\ n\geq 1,$
$$\frac{1}{2}\leq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\ln(n)\leq\frac{3}{2}.$$

---

My attempt:

Regard $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$ as the lower integral of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ from $1$ to $n.$ Then we have the relation $$1+\int_1^nf(x)dx\geq\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}.$$
Therefore, $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\int_1^nf(x)dx\leq1\leq\frac{3}{2}.$$

But how do we establish the inequality on the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that $\frac{1}{x}$ a convex function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence the error of the "trapezoidal approximation"
$$\int_{1}^{n}\frac{dx}{x}-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n-1}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$
is negative. This gives:
$$\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{j}\right)-\log n>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}.$$